# Stack for loop vs while loop (c++)

Tags: c++, stack

Why can't I print all of the items in a stack using a for loop? For some reason it only prints out 3 and 2 but is missing the 1. However, when I comment out the `for` loop and use the `while` loop below, it works perfectly. I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is with the `for` loop because I've traced it out and it should include the 1 as well. Size is 3, so when I=0 we print 3 and pop. When I=1 we print 2 and pop, and when I=2 we print 1 and pop. Then I=3 and we exit the loop. Could someone kindly explain the issue? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::stack;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    stack<int> nums;
    
    nums.push(1);
    nums.push(2);
    nums.push(3);
    
    cout << "Size is: " << nums.size() << endl;

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << nums.top() << endl;
        nums.pop();
    }
    */
    
    while (!nums.empty())
    {
        cout << nums.top() << endl;
        nums.pop();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
{
    cout << nums.top() << endl;
    nums.pop();
}
```

you are *both* incrementing `i`, as well as modifying the size of `nums` when you do `pop()`. This means you are *over-counting* in each iteration, and are going to skip printing the bottom half of the stack in this loop.

e.g. if the stack size is 3, then:

```
iteration 1: i = 0, nums.size() = 3
iteration 2: i = 1, nums.size() = 2
iteration 3: i = 2, nums.size() = 1 (oops, comparison fails here)
```

If you want similar behavior to the `while` loop, you can pre-compute the size of `nums`, and use that in the condition:

```
for (int i = 0, size = nums.size(); i < size; i++)
{
    cout << nums.top() << endl;
    nums.pop();
}
```

Comment: other possibilities: `for (int i = 0; nums.size() != 0; i++)` or `for (int i = 0; !nums.empty(); i++)`
`

Comment: @Serge What's the point of `i` in those loops you showed? Looks like the `while` version OP showed.

Comment: There is no point to of `i` in any of mine or your examples. I assume that OP just needs it for something else. Otherwise there is yet another form like `for(;!nums.empty();)` which is just equivalent to `while`.

Comment: @Serge In my answer, at least the `i` is being *used* (even if there are other ways of writing it). In your examples, it could *literally* be deleted. There's a difference.